# Odata Wcf data service .NET client event notification

Tags: c#, wcf, odata, wcf-data-services

I am trying to implementing event notification in client when some data has been changed at server side so that the client doesn't have to poll every time. Earlier I am using WCF service in this with duplex channel and callback contract its possible to notify client if something happen.

```
[ServiceContract(CallbackContract = typeof(ILatchingEvent))]
```

But I am not sure how it should be implemented in WCF data service? Has anyone tried this.

I have heard about Notification Hubs from Azure which do the push notification, but I don't know how to implement it without using it in .NET client.

Any help is deeply appreciated.!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok I am assuming you are using Desktop client and WCF data service.
So what I think its not possible to get events from WCF data service (I am not sure though), but can't you combine WCF service and ODATA to reach your goal.

Steps:

1) Make WCF service duplex channel and callback on interface as you have mentioned in your question.

2) Make another interface for Registering the events.

3) Now event can be generated using WCF service if the client is registered.

4) Now when event is fired on the client side, you can call your service operation on ODATA Data service.

I hope this will help :) if you require help with code let me know.

Comment: Seems a valid solution, but as I mentioned in the question I am only using WCF data service, is it not possible to do only with data service.

Comment: I have not worked much with Odata and as I mentioned in I am not sure if it is possible to generate event notification in Wcf data service, according to the documentation which I have looked in I didn't find anything about event notification.

Answer (score 0):

I suppose client runs on Windows.

If client is traditional desktop application, then push notifications do not work.

If client is Windows Store application, then read [this article](http://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/notification-hubs-windows-store-dotnet-get-started/) to get start with Azure Notification Hubs.

Comment: Absolutely agree with you, that's what I have read. But isn't there some another way to fire events at client side. I am sure there should be some trick or may be I am wrong...

Comment: There are some frameworks like SignalR which may solve push-to-client scenario for browser-based clients. 

Also WCF callback may be used for desktop application as it was described by MKMohanty. 

For mobile platforms native push notification system seems to be more efficient and Azure Notification Hubs may help here.

So, particular solution depends on what you have.

Comment: Thanks for reply, ya I asked this question because i am new in ODATA and thought there should some mechanism there in ODATA for event notification for desktop client. But now I guess I have to settle for alternative solution which you and MKMohanty has tell